# Where can i find url to download edge browser like we have for chrome

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, windows-server-2016, microsoft-edge-chromium

Could i get the link to urls list to download edge browser setup file. Like we have for chrome as per below link,

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to download various versions of EdgeDriver for testing. You can refer to the official link:
`https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/`

It mainly contains the driver download methods for Edge of each Channel. If you still need older versions of drivers, you can find them here:[image]

`https://msedgewebdriverstorage.z22.web.core.windows.net/`

Comment: My question is to download edge browser using url with wget from windows command prompt. Edge driver url I already have it.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to fully meet your needs. You can download the Edge browser, but you can't specify the version. like this: `winget install Microsoft.Edge.Beta`. So if you need specific versions, you must download them from the corresponding official channel.